# Paypal credit card error type

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Good morning, I'm using the paypal express checkout for my website. When the customer pays for the stuff, it is redirected to paypal to login or insert credit card detailt, sometime paypal give an error of card not valid, how can I check the specific credit card error? (credit card expired, not enough funds, credit card not valid)?

The error code the customer receives is 10486

Answer (score 0):

here is a link to a complete list of API error codes: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/
If there is an issue with the card generally the message will be purposely vague; the best course of action is usually a different funding source.